# Creating core data for chat app in swift

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, relationships

I’m developing an application similar to an simple chat app and I need to use core data to save/fetch the chats based on specific user. I have now successfully created a model to save users, now I need to link them to their chats.
For Saving user data I’ve created  Entity UserData and  below are my swift files

**UserData+CoreDataProperties.swift**

```
import Foundation
import CoreData

extension UserData {

    @NSManaged var firstName: String?
    @NSManaged var userStatus: String?
    @NSManaged var userId: String?
    @NSManaged var userStatus: String?
    @NSManaged var lastName: String?
    @NSManaged var profilePic: String?

}
```

**UserData.swift**

```
class UserData: NSManagedObject {


    convenience init(WithDictionary dict:NSDictionary){


        let appDelegate =  UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate

        let managedContext = appDelegate.managedObjectContext

        let newEntity =  NSEntityDescription.entityForName("UserData", inManagedObjectContext:managedContext)

        // initializer on NSManagedObject class
        self.init(entity: newEntity!, insertIntoManagedObjectContext: managedContext)

        self.userId =  (dict.valueForKey(ID) != nil) && !(dict.valueForKey(ID) is NSNull)
            ? dict.valueForKey(ID) as! String
            : ""

       //similary initializing other variables

        //Saving to database

        do {
            try managedContext.save()

        } catch let error as NSError  {
            print("Could not save \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
        }

    }
```

I was able to successfully save the user list using this class. Now I’ve created a ChatData Entity, below is its structure.

**ChatData+CoreDataProperties.swift**

```
import Foundation
import CoreData

extension ChatData {

    @NSManaged var chatId: String?
    @NSManaged var chatOwnerName: String?
    @NSManaged var chatReadStatus: Boolean?
    @NSManaged var chatText: String?
    @NSManaged var chatTimestamp: String?
    @NSManaged var chatType: String?
    @NSManaged var imageData: String?
    @NSManaged var imageUrl: String?

}
```

Now for each specific user I should be able to create multiple ChatData objects corresponding to particular userId. I don’t have much experience with core data. I’ve looked at some samples on creating relationship, but I’m still not sure how it works. Do I need to create a relationship? If so how should I do it to make this work?

Comment: Tried realm database: http://realm.io/ ? A lot easier to use than Core Data, no need to setup any Core Data boilerplate code.

Comment: Yes, use a relationship. @Zhang you should also mention realm limitations of you come to recommend it, particularly while not giving any hint how it might help with the question asked...

Comment: I am not aware of realm limitations, I'm no expert in it, it does the job for me. The only thing I know is it doesn't have iCloud synchronisation like CoreData does. I don't want to be giving misleading limitations about something I'm no expert in :D Also, this is a comment as well as a question-comment, not an answer :D

Comment: I created two relationships chats(UserData) and users(ChatData). chats has To-Manyrelationship and inverse to users and users have inverse to chats. Do I have to set parent entity of ChatData to UserData. What is parent entity for if we can just describe relationship?

Comment: @Zhang recommending a different tool is not a useful comment **unless that tool specifically solves the problem the person is having**. You have not indicated that it does.

Comment: @TomHarrington when I look at a question, I also think about the ultimate goal the user is trying to achieve. This question could be interpreted as "I'm new to app dev, I want to build chat app with User entity and Message entity but I only heard of CoreData and here I am, trying to make it work" OR "I am building chat app and I absolutely want to use CoreData, I don't want to use anything else". The poster's ultimate goal may possibly be to build a simple chat app to learn app dev, whether he uses CoreData or Realm to achieve that goal may not matter to him. Hence my suggestion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can modify `UserData` like this

```
extension UserData {
   @NSManaged var firstName: String?
   @NSManaged var userStatus: String?
   @NSManaged var userId: String?
   @NSManaged var userStatus: String?
   @NSManaged var lastName: String?
   @NSManaged var profilePic: String?
   @NSManaged var chats: Set<ChatData>?
}
```

and `ChatData` like this

```
extension ChatData {
   @NSManaged var chatId: String?
   @NSManaged var chatOwnerName: String?
   @NSManaged var chatReadStatus: Boolean?
   @NSManaged var chatText: String?
   @NSManaged var chatTimestamp: String?
   @NSManaged var chatType: String?
   @NSManaged var imageData: String?
   @NSManaged var imageUrl: String?
   @NSManaged var user: UserData?
}
```

The corresponding core data model has a one-to-many releationship from UserData to ChatData (some attributes are missing):

[image]

Some code that shows how you can create a user with two messages:

```
let user=userWithName("MyName")
let chat01=chatWithText("How do you doing?")
let chat02=chatWithText("Fine.")
user?.chats=[chat01!,chat02!]
let appDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate
appDelegate.saveContext()
```

with

```
func userWithName(name:String) -> UserData? {
    let appDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate
    let managedContext = appDelegate.managedObjectContext
    let userEntity =  NSEntityDescription.entityForName("UserData", inManagedObjectContext:managedContext)
    let user = NSManagedObject(entity: userEntity!, insertIntoManagedObjectContext: managedContext) as! UserData
    user.firstName=name
    return user
}

func chatWithText(text:String) -> ChatData? {
    let appDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate
    let managedContext = appDelegate.managedObjectContext
    let chatEntity =  NSEntityDescription.entityForName("ChatData", inManagedObjectContext:managedContext)
    let chat = NSManagedObject(entity: chatEntity!, insertIntoManagedObjectContext: managedContext) as! ChatData
    chat.chatText=text
    return chat
}
```